# Check if command exists for setting alias in tcshrc

Tags: csh, tcsh

I check if a command exists in Bourne shell as below:

```
if [ "$(command -v emacs)" 2>&1 ]; then alias emacs='emacs -nw'; fi
```

I am aware that tcsh is not the best shell for shell scripting but how do I implement the above scenario in tcshrc ?

Comment: Why is this tagged with "freebsd"? Seems like a generic `csh`-question - would apply even under Cygwin...

Comment: I thought it would be a good idea as csh is default root shell. But I got you :)

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a simple solution:

```
/usr/bin/which -s emacs && alias emacs emacs -nw
```

The full path of `which` is needed because `tcsh` has own `which` which search in aliases too. Please note there isn't equal sign in `alias`.

Comment: Got `[: /usr/bin/which: unexpected operator` error

Comment: However ```/usr/bin/which -s <command> && echo "Installed"``` works :)

Thanks :)

Comment: Sorry, you've right - I hurried. Edited.

Comment: No problems... Do you use FreeBSD?

Comment: Yes. Why do you ask?

Comment: Well nothing :)